install forge Error loading python DLL: python312.dll. Cant find this module
I am using install forge to create a Windows installer for my app. I create the dist folder using pyinstaller. In there I find the .exe and many files and folders. If I start this .exe everything works fine! When I ckeck the _internal folder I can find the python312.dll file.
In install forge I follow all the steps to create the installer: upload all the files (including python312.dll) and all the folders needed to run the program. Even when I click the build button and the process ends there is a successfully message that everythings is ok. Even I can check python312.dll was uploaded.
Then I install the app in my computer and when I click on the icon a message appears: Error loading python DLL: python312.dll. Cant find this module
What am I missing?
I am using Windows 11
I recently realize that the total error message is:
enter image description here
and the path in the image contains a _internal folder that does not exist in my computer.
enter image description here
Pyinstaller create that folder next to the .exe and there it storages all the files, including the python312.dll. does it have something to do with some set up in the .spec file?
thanks in advance!
enter image description here

I think you are using your development file paths in the build or forget to specify where you want to place a binary in the build.

I faced a similar issue. In the Install Forge, you must add your whole _internal folder and just your exe file. The assets folders must also be inside the _internal folder. This way you won't get the error. This worked for me.

wow man! Thanks a lot! Utsav Mehta was correct. I did what he said and now my app can be installed in my computer (and runs ok). Just add the complete _internal folder (as a whole) in the files section of the install forge and also upload the .exe as a file. You must end with two objects in the file section: .exe and _internal folder (also must contains all the assets folder inside)
